# Reduce array of promises instead of mapping and filtering undefined/null values

Tags: node.js, typescript

Currently in our API-server code we have the following:

```
async someAsyncMethod() {
    // ...
    let products = await Promise.all(shopStructure.map(async entry => {
                try {
                    const serviceResponse = await this.requestService.someService(entry);
                    return ProductMapper.map(entry, serviceResponse);
                } catch (err) {
                    this.logger.error('...');
                    return undefined;
                }
            }));
    products = products.filter(s => s);
    return products;
}
```

How would I use reduce here in order to get rid of the filter operation?

I tried using the following:

```
async someAsyncMethod() {
    // ...
    const products = await Promise.all(shopStructure.reduce(async (accumulator, entry) => {
                try {
                    const serviceResponse = await this.requestService.someService(entry);
                    accumulator.push(ProductMapper.map(entry, serviceResponse));
                } catch (err) {
                    this.logger.error('...');
                }
                return accumulator;
            },[]));
    return products;
}
```

but this results in compile errors (`"No overload matches this call", "Argument of type ... is not assignable to parameter of type <never>"`).

Maybe there's another elegant way to do this? Note that I deliberately use `Promise.all` instead of `for...of` for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `reduce` is the right tool here. You need to wait for `n` Promises to resolve, where `n` is the length of the `shopStructure`; the input array and the array of Promises that `Promise.all` needs are one-to-one, so `.map` and `Promise.all` *definitely is* the right approach.

You can avoid using `.filter` if you want by pushing to an array instead:

```
async someAsyncMethod() {
  const products = [];
  await Promise.all(shopStructure.map(entry => (
    this.requestService.someService(entry)
      .then(serviceResponse => products.push(ProductMapper.map(entry, serviceResponse)))
      .catch(err => { this.logger.error('...'); })
  )));
  return products;
}
```

I don't think there's a good-looking way to use `reduce`, since the `.map` is already essential.

Comment: Thanks for your input, it looks better this way. But I would lose the shopStructure array order like this, if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: That's true, but by filtering out the error items, you're already losing most of the order information. If the order is useful, consider returning a [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) call instead, and filter in the consumer (while it can check the index as well while iterating).

Comment: Thanks, I'll use that :)